# Transforming a Github user into an organization

Tags: github

I created a new Github user and then I tried to convert that user into an organization but I get "No owners or emails were submitted." error. In the Choose an Organization owner textbox, I entered my another Github account username. I followed Github help https://help.github.com/articles/converting-a-user-into-an-organization but I am unable to convert a user to an organization. Any help?

Answer (score 34):

Once you have entered the account name of the new owner, you then need to press the 'choose' button in order to actually select the new owner.

Pressing 'create organization' should then work.

Comment: I am embarrassed how long it took me to realize I had to press the 'Choose' button.

Comment: I had this same issue... unfortunately not a great UX choice.